# How to pull billing address from apple pay

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I'm trying to implement ApplePay, but my server api requires me to send billing address. Is there a way to pull billing address that i entered when apple pay screen appeared and i entered it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a property in [PKPayment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPayment_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PKPayment/billingContact). A reference from [Apple developer site](http://To%20initiate%20a%20payment,%20your%20app%20creates%20a%20payment%20request.%20This%20request%20includes%20the%20subtotal%20for%20the%20services%20and%20goods%20purchased,%20as%20well%20as%20any%20additional%20charges%20for%20tax,%20shipping,%20or%20discounts.%20Pass%20this%20request%20to%20a%20payment%20authorization%20view%20controller,%20which%20displays%20the%20request%20to%20the%20user%20and%20prompts%20for%20any%20needed%20information,%20such%20as%20a%20shipping%20or%20billing%20address.).

> To initiate a payment, your app creates a payment request. This
>   request includes the subtotal for the services and goods purchased, as
>   well as any additional charges for tax, shipping, or discounts. Pass
>   this request to a payment authorization view controller, which
>   displays the request to the user and prompts for any needed
>   information, such as a shipping or billing address.

I can recommend you to read these two links above.

Comment: Thank you. I see now, i can pull `billingContact`